# Change buttons text and progressbar colors with Anko

Tags: android, kotlin, alert, anko

I need to change the default text colors of Anko alerts. I have the same problem with progressbars inside progressDialogs. It would be nice to customize them and even the description/title text colors or the alerts background colors.

Comment: Can we see some code which you are trying to open progressDialog?